# Максимальное количество памяти

Tags: c

Как получить максимальное значение в байтах, которое может получить программа на C через вызов malloc?

Сейчас я пробую наращивать размер памяти шаг за шагом: 1 Мб, 2 Мб, ... 512 Мб и так далее, пока память выделяется. Если память не выделилась, то это реальный предел. Какие еще существуют способы?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

malloc выделяет память в стандартной куче, а она определяется параметром /heapsize для VC++. Больше 2Гб не может быть (впрочем тут наверняка не уверен). В серьезных приложениях, очень активно работающих с памятью, создают свою кучу(кучи) а там уже ограничения задаются платформой.

В любом случае, вам нет необходимости определять размер кучи таким странным образом, поскольку он у вас определен на момент компиляции.

Answer (score 1):

Для unixes см. getrlimit()
пробуй sbrk()/brk()

Answer (score 0):

Под Windows? 3Гб Ваш предел [с флажком `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`; без него — 2 Гб] ;).

Comment: x68_64-приложения тоже имеют такое ограничение?

Comment: Если приложение, действительно, 64-битное, то 2 гига без флажка и много-много с флажком (8Тб, если не ошибаюсь).

Comment: вопрос то бы не про ограничения или особенности реализации windows...

Comment: Если так, то тем более зависит только от разрядности системы и приложения. Если оба нормальные 64 разряда имеют, то и размер либо "практически безграничен", либо упрётся в квоту на память, если таковая имеется.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m вы не правы - см. мой ответ

Comment: Ваш ответ очень частный. Вы сами же сказали, что вопрос не про Windows. И про VC тоже никто не гвоорил ничего.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m опять не правы, прочтите внимательнее мой ответ - учитесь читать. написал как определяется в VC. В других компиляторах не знаю, по этому не написал, но суть про стандартную кучу от этого не меняется и не зависит от компилятора.

Comment: Нет, вы написали про стандартную кучу VC Runtime. Но это не значит, что весь мир так устроен. Прочтите http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html

Comment: @cy6erGn0m опять мимо, VC Runtime тут не причем. Со стандартной кучей в Windows все одинаково работают, поскольку так уж реализовано управление памятью в windows. Про ликус не стану комментировать, поскольку не в тему ваша ссылка.

Comment: @IAZ обычно на стадии компиляции исходного кода уже известен компилятор, рантайм и операционная система. Так что ограничение по памяти можно вычислить в compile-time. Так что всё ответы уместны — автор не дал достаточно конкретики.

Comment: Ни при чём? А как насчёт malloc? Выглядит так, будто вы считаете, что malloc из VCRuntime и Global/LocalAlloc из WinAPI - одно и то же. Вот как раз под Windows-VC в тех случаях, когда не хочется мучаться с malloc и дурными лимитами, то тогда и рекомендуется использовать стандартную кучу. В Linux это отдано на откуп libc, которая в свою очередь при необходимости увеличивает кучу.

Comment: Однако, ваш ответ верен с некоторой точки зрения. Поскольку вопрос был про malloc и наверняка речь о VC+Windows.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m вы ничего не поняли из моего объяснения :( да я считаю и прямым текстом говорю, что malloc реализовано в windows через HeapAlloc для стандартной кучи, и заметьте ТОЛЬКО со стандартной кучей работает. Если нужна "не стандартная" сами вызывайте HeapCreate а затем HeapAlloc.